# How to set up IIS7 site to be Https

Tags: iis, iis-7

Hi I setup my site on my dev machine and was able to browse to it effectively.

The binding it had was http IP address all unassigned on port 80.

When I browse from IIS it goes to http://localhost/ and the site looks as expected

I then wanted to make it an https site only so I changed the binding to:

https IP address all unassigned on port 443.

I then selected the localcert as the SSL certificate.

When I browse from IIS it goes to https://localhost/ which is what I would expect but instead of seeing my site I see a blue IIS7 homepage with different language versions of 'Welcome' on it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is a q for webmasters...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This site should help:  http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/144/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis-7/